# -lsqlite3 causing Apple Mach-O linker errors

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, linker-errors, mach-o

I installed the Facebook SDK and followed one of their tutorials in order to provide some very basic FB functionality to my app. The app, and the FB integration seems to work just fine so I think I did a decent job with the tutorial.  When I attempt to Archive the project so that I can throw a build up on TestFlight, I get a Failure due to 15 linker errors, that looks like the below text (I copied it from the app log).  It seems to be related to lsqlite3.0, which the FB tute said to add to the build settings under 'other linkage'.  I am not quite sure what to do to resolve. Could I get some advice?  That would be super awesome, thanks!  Here are the errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      ___23-[FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: One interesting thing to note is that these errors only surface when I need to Archive. I can run the app in the simulator, as well as on my device without getting the errors. What does that mean?

Comment: And a side question: whats a good way for a newbie to earn rep here? I don't think I am in a position to be administering advice given my low level of expertise...

Comment: You earn rep by asking good questions, or by answering... to start with remove the image you cannot post and type the error in by hand.

Comment: Excellent advice Kendall, I am going to append the errors to the description now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive uses a release build by default and your linker setting are only set for debug.  Check that your linker settings are valid for release build.

Comment: Hi stackmonster, thank you for the answer. I am fairly certain I have a valid release (or distribution) provisioning profile, and my linker settings look like the following:

Comment: Other Linker Flags: <Multiple values>

Comment: Under both of these, there is a statement to the effect of "Any architecture, any SDK". One thing I am not sure about is the <multiple values> since the values are exactly the same for both debug as well as for release.

Comment: The error shows you are clearly not linking to sqlite for your target platform.

Comment: I tend to agree with that, but the linker settings say that I am. Perhaps removing and re-adding would do the trick?

Comment: is sqlite listed under link with libraries under build phases?

Comment: it may be that it cant find the binary

Comment: Arg. Removing the -lsqlite3.0 from both the debug and release lines of the linker settings, and then re-adding them resolved the problem. OMG I was pulling my hair out. Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: stackmonster and kendall, how can I bump your rep for helping out?

Comment: Don't worry about it.  Glad you solved your issue.  You will also get points for accepting the answer.